# Void Pointer Cast Error?

Tags: c, pointers, void

I am working with a void pointer in my c program. I have a if statement that forces the printing of a data set to a 32-byte boundary.

** I should note, that I'm trying to modify the address of the mem pointer to shift it to a boundary **

I'm getting the following error thrown:

```
Operation between types "void*" and "int" is not allowed
```

My code is as follows:

```
if(((int)mem % 32) != 0)   
    mem -= ((int)mem % 32);
```

where mem is defined as:

```
void *mem
```

Comment: try casting to a long

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
void * mem;                   // input

char * p = mem;               // byte-wise arithmetic
uintptr_t n = (uintptr_t) p;  // integral arithmetic

p -= n % 32                   // align

mem = p;                      // output
```

Note that this assumes that the memory *before* the address `mem` points to has already been allocated and is also yours.

You can of course compress the code into a single statement:

```
mem = (char *) mem - ((uintptr_t) mem % 32);
```

Beware that the pointer conversions are generally implementation defined. There's no standard way to reason about "alignment", and the integral value obtained from a pointer may or may not have anything to do with the layout of the memory in the hardware.

Comment: It would be simpler to just do the alignment completely on n and then simply cast back to void* (no p involved).

Comment: @PeterSchneider: That's true, thanks. You need to write some appropriate expression, though, perhaps involving a bit mask or some division.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: E.g. `mem = (void *) (((uintptr_t) mem >> 5) << 5);`

Comment: Doing something on bit level is nice because it shows what's going on. One could also just mask with ~0xf or whatever to make it even clearer (and faster, possibly). But I simply envisioned `void * mem; uintptr_t n = (uintptr_t)mem; n -= n%32; mem = (void *)n;`.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Yeah, many ways to skin that cat. They probably all generate the same machine code, so it's just a matter of taste and what's easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do pointer arithmetics with a `void *`:

```
mem -= ((int)mem % 32);
```

is not defined, as `*mem` has no "intrinsic size".

There may be compilers out there (hello, `gcc`!) which allow this as an extension, but in general, you can only do pointer arithmetics on pointers of types which have a size, such as `char *`, `int *` etc.